# Calling PHP function using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have 3 buttons in my html page, say *ADD*, *UPDATE* & *DELETE*. And I have written a PHP class *DBComm* in a PHP file *dbutils.php* which contains three functions *add()*, *update()* & *delete()* for adding, updating & deleting data in the database. 
What I want to do is, on submission of the page, I want to create an instance of the PHP class and would be able to call the corresponding PHP function in that class. I wrote the AJAX code,

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "dbutils.php", true);
```

But, if I write like this, I may need to use three php files for handling each event, like *Add.php*, *Update.php* & *Delete.php*. Is there any option in AJAX for creating an instance of the class and to invoke a particular function in that class so that I can keep all the related things in the same place, ie in the class itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can send parameters with xmlhttp

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", "dbutils.php", true); 
var params = "function=" + function + "&paramater=" + parameter; 
xmlHttp.send(params);
```

on the php side in dbutils file you can use your function. for example

```
function add(){}
function delete(){}
function edit(){}
if(in_array($_POST['function'],array('add','edit','delete'))
{
     //call the function
     $_POST['function']();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a variable with ajax for add, update and delete and check with corresponding variable to call the function in php.

Comment: means, like an event handler php file ? action keys are to be passed to the handler ?